# Does Unity support Unicode 1000-1FFF Block?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unicode

I've been at this for hours, trying to figure out why my calculator wont take my character.  I've been asking all over the place, googling "Unity unicode" and people got Chinese to work... so I'm just puzzled.

I try something as simple as:

```
Debug.Log("\u154D");
```

And it just comes back blank.  I did the same with:

```
Debug.Log("\u0190");
```

It happily returns:

```
Ɛ
```

Does Unity not have 1000-1FFF included?
If not, I want to find a way to import it.  The font Arial accepts U+154D, so it's just frustrating.

Comment: Arial does not contain glyphs for these characters (which you can easily verify in the Character Map).

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9yavt6
http://prntscr.com/9yaw70
Then, how did I do that?

Comment: @Buffoonery Notepad uses a set of fallback fonts for glyphs if the selected font is missing any.

Comment: So, each font has a set of fallback fonts individually set for each one?
Because I put in different fonts and they each had different versions of the symbol I used.
Ok, so basically I have to find out which fonts can use this- probably Code2000- and say,
"If (a == "this value"), then use this font instead of the default" ?
That's annoying, but I guess I'll give it a try.